# Pass an array of bytes to T4 Template code into another array of same type

Tags: c#, t4

I'm using T4Template and codeDOM to create an assembly using the following code:

```
CompilerParameters Params = new CompilerParameters();
            Params.GenerateExecutable = true;
            Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            Params.OutputAssembly = "myfile.exe";

            RuntimeTextTemplate1 RTT = new RuntimeTextTemplate1();
            string Source = RTT.TransformText();

            CompilerResults Create = new CSharpCodeProvider().CompileAssemblyFromSource(Params, Source);
```

The Template looks like this ( for moment ) :

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
namespace Application
{
  class Program
  {
     static void Main()
     {
       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       //And some code for creating a file with the bytes in the buffer.
     }
  }
}
```

In the Main application I have a byte array which contains some bytes of a certain application , these bytes are loaded into the array at runtime.

My question is :

- How can I pass the array of bytes which contains data(bytes) into the
  T4Template in the ( `byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];` ) so when the
  assembly is created with the code written in the Template,the array
  should contain the bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd prefer to pass the data to the generated code at runtime, but if you really need to embed it within your generated assembly, then you could do something like this:

Add a class feature block with a byte array parameter as a member in it, then you'll be able to set that from your runtime template and access it in the template.  Something like the following

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
namespace Application
{
  class Program
  {
     static void Main()
     {
       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024] { <#= BufferValue.Select(b => "0x" + b.ToString("X2")).Aggregate((f, s) => f + ", " + s) #> };
       //And some code for creating a file with the bytes in the buffer.
     }
  }
}
<#+

public byte[] BufferValue { get; set; } 

#>
```

Then just set `RTT.BufferValue` to your array before invoking the template.